# apache/Magento user's Linux home directory (for private RSA key)

Tags: authentication, sftp, rsa

`apache` runs Magento on our Linux server, and I'm trying to find out where the home directory for this user would be. I need to place a private key for SFTP access for Magento's extension.

There is `/var/www`, so would I have a directory, `/var/www/.ssh/` here and put the private key there?

Furthermore, I'm not even sure if this will work when a Magento extension will attempt to upload a file via key-anthenticating SFTP. I do have the password-authentication SFTP already set up, and that works great. This might be a little off-topic, however.

Answer (score 0):

On a terminal, do `grep "apache" /etc/passwd`

You should get something like

`apache:x:33:33:apache:/var/www:/bin/sh`

That second-last column (`/var/www` in my example) is the home directory of apache